# MFC: How do you add a bitmap to CMenu items added on OnInitMenuPopup?

Tags: winapi, mfc, cmenu

I need to add custom menu items as needed.   I found `OnInitMenuPopup` (WM_INITMENUPOPUP) does what I need but I can't get an icon to show next to the text on the menu?   I've tried a 16x16 png graphic using `m_MyGraphic` as a `CPngImage`, I've tried attaching it to a `CBitmap`, I've tried saving the graphic as a .bmp and loading as `CBitmap`.  I've tried not setting the graphic on the load, but then trying to do it with `SetMenuItemBitmaps()`, I've tried a 13x13 graphic, I've tried a 15x15 graphic (which matches `GetMenuCheckMarkDimensions()`).  Never does a graphic show next to the menu item?  What am I doing wrong or missing?

TIA!

```
void CMainFrame::OnInitMenuPopup(CMenu* pPopupMenu, UINT nIndex, BOOL bSysMenu)
{
  // add items
  if (pPopupMenu && pPopupMenu->GetMenuItemCount() > 0 && pPopupMenu->GetMenuItemID(0) == ID_MY_EXPECTED_ID) {
    // loop though and add menu items
    for (UINT i=0; i<theApp.m_MyList.GetCount(); i++) {
      CString s;
      s.Format(_T("%i: %s"), i, theApp.m_MyList[i].String);
      MENUITEMINFO mii={};
      mii.cbSize=sizeof(mii);
      mii.fMask=MIIM_ID|MIIM_STRING|MIIM_BITMAP;
      mii.wID=ID_MY_RANGE_0+i;
      mii.dwTypeData=s.GetBuffer();
      mii.hbmpItem=(HBITMAP)m_MyBitmap.GetSafeHandle();
      pPopupMenu->InsertMenuItem(i+1, &mii, TRUE);
      // not working above so tried using this as well but it doesn't work either:
      //pPopupMenu->SetMenuItemBitmaps(i+1, MF_BYPOSITION, &m_MyBitmap, &m_MyBitmap);
    }
  }

  CFrameWndEx::OnInitMenuPopup(pPopupMenu, nIndex, bSysMenu);
}
```

Comment: That should work. How do you load your `m_MyBitmap` bitmap, can you show your code?

Comment: You are trying to modify a menu that your application creates/maintains? Or are you trying to modify a system menu that the system provides?

Comment: You don't usually need to do all this, MFC will display bitmaps in your menu items if you add a TOOLBAR resource and assign the same IDs as the ones in your menu (you don't need to create or display the toolbar). The icons are by default 16×15 pixels large, so for 4 items for example you will need a bitmap 60×15 pixels large.

Comment: Yeah, for this I have a `CMFCDropDownToolbar` that I add items to using a shared icon loaded with the toolbar.  The icon for it is in there which the menus won't pick up.  I had to do it myself, I found a workaround, see answer.

Comment: I load the bitmap simply with `CPngImage m_MyBitmap'   `m_MyBitmap.Load(ID)` - same when trying with CBitmap for a .bmp, etc..  never worked (and looking at MFC code for a `CMFCMenuBar`, it seems to override the bitmaps which explains why it didn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around.  First add `CMFCToolBarMenuButton::m_bAlwaysCallOwnerDraw=TRUE;` somewhere on initialization.

Then handle drawing it:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnDrawMenuImage(CDC* pDC, const CMFCToolBarMenuButton* pMenuButton, const CRect& rectImage)
{
  BOOL result=FALSE;
  if (pMenuButton->m_nID>=ID_MY_RANGE_0 && pMenuButton->m_nID<=ID_MY_RANGE_N) {

    // size to use on menu
    CSize sizemenuimage = CMFCToolBar::GetMenuImageSize();

    // get size of our bitmap
    BITMAP bitmap;
    m_MyBitmap.GetBitmap(&bitmap);

    // create dc to attach bitmap to
      CDC dcmem;
    if (dcmem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC)) {
      // attach bitmap to dc
      CBitmap * poldbitmap=dcmem.SelectObject(&m_MyBitmap);
      if (poldbitmap) {
        // Draw bitmap
        result=pDC->StretchBlt(rectImage.left+(rectImage.Width()-sizemenuimage.cx)/2, 
                               rectImage.top+(rectImage.Height()-sizemenuimage.cy)/2, 
                               sizemenuimage.cx, sizemenuimage.cy, 
                               &dcmem, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
        // Select original object
        dcmem.SelectObject(poldbitmap);
      }
      dcmem.DeleteDC();
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: i have to wait two days.

Comment: @zhu Don't ask people to accept the worst possible solution. This is something that the menu implementation supports as is.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (if you already have the bitmaps for toolbar) is:

```
void CMainFrame::OnInitMenuPopup(CMenu* pPopupMenu, UINT nIndex, BOOL bSysMenu) 
{
    CMDIFrameWnd::OnInitMenuPopup(pPopupMenu, nIndex, bSysMenu);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    HICON hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_TESTMETYPE);
    pPopupMenu->SetMenuItemBitmaps(ID_FILE_NEW, MF_BYCOMMAND, ConvertIconToBitmap(hIcon), NULL);
    ...
    ...
}
```

where **SetMenuItemBitmaps** is defined as:

```
CBitmap* CMainFrame::ConvertIconToBitmap(HICON hIcon)
{
    CDC dc;
    CBitmap bmp;
    CClientDC ClientDC(this);
    dc.CreateCompatibleDC(&ClientDC);
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&ClientDC, 13, 13);
    CBitmap* pOldBmp = (CBitmap*)dc.SelectObject(&bmp);
    ::DrawIconEx(dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, hIcon, 13, 13, 0, (HBRUSH)RGB(255, 255, 255), DI_NORMAL);
    dc.SelectObject(pOldBmp);
    dc.DeleteDC();
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::CopyImage((HANDLE)((HBITMAP)bmp), 
            IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

    return CBitmap::FromHandle(hBitmap);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, already tried that as shown in the question. Maybe has to do with using `CMFCMenuBar`